# View Mongo DB in Mongo compass

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to `MongoDB` and `Node`. I have connected to `Mongo` using below

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testaroo', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection has been made ..")
}).on('error', function(error) {
  console.log("Connection error", error)
});
```

And I created the below model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const marioCharSchema = new schema({
    name: String, // Optional
    weight: Number // Optional
})
const marioCharModel = mongoose.model('mariochar', marioCharSchema);
module.exports = marioCharModel;
```

**EDIT**

Inserting Data

```
const assert = require('assert');
const mariochar = require('../test/models/mariochar')

// Describe tests
describe('Saving records', function () {

    //Create tests
    it("Saving records to database", function (done) {
        

        const char = new mariochar({
            name = "Test",
            weight: 45
        });

        char.save().then(
            function () {
                assert(char.isNew === false)
                done();
            }
        )
    
    })

})
```

And I tried to save a new record to this model and I tested it using `mocha` and it saved successfully. Now I want to view my database and my records using `Mongo compass`.

I tried to connect to `mongodb://localhost/testaroo` on port `27017`
but I couldn't see my database. So what I'm missing here?

**FIXED**

For future viewers I fixed it by passing this option `useUnifiedTopology`: true to the to the MongoClient constructor

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Mydb', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

Comment: How does one see a database exactly?

Comment: I think it's clear what I meant by that .. I want to have a visual representation of my data.

Comment: It is not. You can retrieve documents from a database, what you mean by seeing a database I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Leave it to someone who knows how to view a database and its records

Comment: MongoDb will create database or collection only when there is atleast one document. If it is empty you can't see the the collection or database. Make sure you have successfully inserted data.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh I updated my question to show you how I've inserted data , maybe I did something wrong there but the test is passed once I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mongo` shell to insert and retrieve documents from the database, verify this works.

Use compass to view documents you inserted via the shell, verify this works.

Insert documents in your application and retrieve them via the shell, verify this works.

At this point whatever issue you have between your application and compass should be resolved.